# How to get a cookie in php without refreshing the page?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cookies, time

I currently have this code and two problems:

I get the users timezone with Javascript and post it to the timezone.php via ajax, which sets a cookie with the users time. If the cookie is not set, say on first visit, the page would have to be refreshed in order to show the cookie value. I'm doing this with javascript at the moment, but there has to be another way. Also, since the page refreshes if there is no cookie, users with cookies disabled would get a refresh loop.

Any suggestions on how to solve these problems?

Thank you, 
Markus

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .night {
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php

        if(isset($_COOKIE["time"])) {
            $time = $_COOKIE["time"];
            if($time < 5.5 || $time > 19) {
                $night = true;
            }
        } else {
            echo("
            <script>
              var timezone = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60;

              $(document).ready(function() {
                $.post('timezone.php',{timezone: timezone}, function(data){location.reload(true)});
              });
            </script>
            ");
        }
?>

</head>
<body class="<?php echo $night ? "night" : "day"; ?>">
<?php if($night) {
    echo "It's nighttime! ($time)";
} else {
    echo "It's daytime! ($time)";
} ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**timezone.php:**

```
<?php

$timezone = $_POST["timezone"];

if(isset($timezone)) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT'.($timezone <= 0 ? '' : '+').$timezone);
    $time = date("G") + (date("i")/60);
    setcookie("time", $time);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery Plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie and check if the cookie is set in your $.post method like that

```
 $.post('timezone.php',{timezone: timezone}, function(data){
     if ($.cookie("time") != null) 
         location.reload(true);
});
```

Comment: Can't you do something like post a parameter to the current file (index.php in this case)?

Answer (score 1):

set the class with JavaScript, there is no need for the server.

Comment: I could, but isn't performance better if I do it on the server once the cookie is set?

Comment: Also, when using PHP I only have to request the timezone per Javascript once in a session.

Answer (score 0):

PHP script only runs when a request is made to the server. You could use JS and AJAX, or, if appropriate, an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

you can change index.php:

```
 $.post('timezone.php',{timezone: timezone}, function(data){ 
    if(data=='success'){
        location.reload(true)
    }
 });
```

and in timezone.php:

```
<?php

$timezone = $_POST["timezone"];

if(isset($timezone)) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT'.($timezone <= 0 ? '' : '+').$timezone);
    $time = date("G") + (date("i")/60);
    setcookie("time", $time);
    echo "success";
}

?>
```

Comment: Ok, does this mean it would only echo "success" if the cookie was set? Otherwise this would not make any difference.

Comment: if request not return "success", that mean have got error when get timezone from users, you can try get agian or do everything else:

if(data=='success'){
        location.reload(true)
}else{
   // set timezone not success, we will try get timezone agian or redirect user to other page which allow choose timezone
}

Comment: But the timezone doesn't have anything to do with cookies. I just don't want to create a refresh loop if no cookie gets set.

Comment: yes, we have got 2 thing: + first is when timezone was set in cookie. it will be ok. + second is when timezone was not set in cookie, you can give a alert or to do something else and it will never loop because we only call ajax 1 time.