# Cookie values holding, but not functioning after reload

Tags: jquery

This code below checks if cookies exist, then sets them if none are found.  Then the user can trigger a click event in order to store a new cookie. This code is being used to switch languages in my own custom Google Translate function.

When using `location.reload();` shown below, it loads the cookie values properly but the langauge does not change.  The language DOES change when I re-code this without using `location.reload()`. I would rather re-load the page though.

Is there something I'm missing here?

```
<script>
     jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

     //Click event functionality for drop-down and flag language display
        $("a.nturl").click(function() { 
            $.cookie("language_name", $(this).attr("title"),{ path: "/" });
            $.cookie("flag_url", $(this).find("img").attr("src"),{ path: "/" });
          location.reload();
        });

        $("a.flag").click(function() {           
            $.cookie("language_name", $(this).attr("title"),{ path: "/" });
            $.cookie("flag_url", $(this).find("img").attr("src"),{ path: "/" });
          location.reload();
        });

     $(function() { 
       var language_name = $.cookie("language_name"); 
       var flag_url = $.cookie("flag_url");

                 if(typeof(language_name) == "undefined" || typeof language_name == "object") {
                   //alert("hello");
                  $.cookie("language_name","English");
                  var language_name = $.cookie("language_name");
               }

               if(typeof(flag_url) == "undefined" || typeof flag_url == "object") {

                  $.cookie("flag_url","<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/google-language-translator/images/flags24/unitedstates.png");
                  var flag_url = $.cookie("flag_url");
               }

       $("div.selected").html( "<a class=\"notranslate nturl\" onclick=\"return false;\" href=\"#\"><span class=\"flag\"><img class=\"flagimg flagselect\" src=\"" + flag_url + "\" alt=\"" + language_name + "\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\"></span>" + language_name + "</a>");

       $.removeCookie("language_name");
       $.removeCookie("flag_url");

     });

       $(function() { 
               var language_name = $.cookie("language_name");
               var flag_url = $.cookie("flag_url");
               var language_name = $.cookie('language_name');
                  if (language_name == "English") {
                      $('.en').css('display','none'); 
                      $('.selected').click(function() { $('.en').css('display','none');  }); 
                  } 

                  if (language_name == "Spanish") {
                  //alert(language_name);
                      $('.selected').click(function() { $('.es').css('display','none'); }); 
                  }

               $("div.selected").html( "<a class=\"notranslate nturl\" onclick=\"return false;\" href=\"#\"><span class=\"flag\"><img class=\"flagimg flagselect\" src=\"" + flag_url + "\" alt=\"" + language_name + "\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\"></span>" + language_name + "</a>");

            });             
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your language is overwritten in this line:

```
$.cookie("language_name", $(this).attr("title"),{ path: "/" });
```

The `title` attribute is empty as this code shows:

```
$("div.selected").html( "<a class=\"notranslate nturl\" onclick=\"return false;\" href=\"#\"><span class=\"flag\"><img class=\"flagimg flagselect\" src=\"" + flag_url + "\" alt=\"" + language_name + "\" height=\"16\" width=\"16\"></span>" + language_name + "</a>");
```

Notice that `<a>` ***does not*** have a `title` attribute

```
<a class=\"notranslate nturl\" onclick=\"return false;\" href=\"#\">
```

I think that you want this:

```
$.cookie("language_name", $(this).find("img").attr("title"),{ path: "/" });
```

One more thing, you should use delegated event handler because you're creating your DOM dynamically.

```
$(document).on("click","a.nturl",function() { 
            $.cookie("language_name", $(this).find("img").attr("title"),{ path: "/" });
            $.cookie("flag_url", $(this).find("img").attr("src"),{ path: "/" });
          location.reload();
        });

        $(document).on("click","a.flag",function() {           
            $.cookie("language_name", $(this).find("img").attr("title"),{ path: "/" });
            $.cookie("flag_url", $(this).find("img").attr("src"),{ path: "/" });
          location.reload();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Khanh TO, can you see any reason that location.reload would not work in this situation, I corrected the errors and it's not working.  And what do you mean by your first line in the answer - meaning "overridden?"

Comment: @Rob Myrick: I mean you set the "language_name" to an empty value which clears it.

Comment: thank you.  Yes, I correct that and it's still not working.  The cookies actually hold values, but somehow this is not working with Google Translate

Comment: that didn't work, that actually stopped the cookie values from reloading properly.  There's probably more to this than you can see.  If you would like to take a look offline, I would be happy to show you.  Thanks either way.

Comment: Here's the link to the translator drop-down (check in the sidebar) http://ng-sandbox.com/excargo2/about-us/

Comment: I have changed back to my original code, which located directly in the source.

Comment: @Rob Myrick: I cannot read your `doGoogleLanguageTranslator` code. I think the problem is: when you finish executing something inside `doGoogleLanguageTranslator` (maybe translate your page), but when you call `location.reload();`, all your work done inside `doGoogleLanguageTranslator` is gone because the page is refreshed with a completely new page.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need server logic to localize your data then could you set JavaScript values and cookie? This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327166/how-to-get-a-cookie-in-php-without-refreshing-the-page) is similar.